# React backgroundImage inline style not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried everything I can think of, as well as Googled this to death. I cannot get React to load a background image using inline styles. Here is my code:

```
const url = './assets/backgrounds/terzo1.jpg'
const style = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
}

const Layout = props => (
  <div style={style}>
    TEXT
  </div>
)

export default Layout
```

My assets folder is in the same folder as the Layout component.

I will note that I am using Create-react-app.

Thanks

Comment: what bundler are you using? and with what config?

Comment: I'm using: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app I cannot modify the configuration without ejecting. Images defined in CSS files imported in as import './file.css' work fine. My goal is to dynamically load a background, which is why I am not using that method.

Comment: with react you need to import 
import img from '../../img/img.png';

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using create-react-app, for loading images and using them in your JS and CSS files, there are two approaches one could take.

### Images on public folder

You can add your images in a directory inside public directory and use them as follows:

```
const style = {backgroundImage: 'url(/images/some-image.png)'}
```

### Images in the same directory as your CSS or JS files

If you want to use images relatively and import them dynamically, You should put your images in the same directory as the CSS or Component that you want to use image in. One of the best ways to structure your codebase is to use component scoped structure. In this way, all stuff related to a component will go in the component's directory. This contains the images too.

For more info:

- [Use public folder for general assets outside of src directory](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)
- [Import images directly into the component file in a scoped structure](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#docsNav)

Comment: Worked like a hot damn. Thanks!

Comment: @Kainan Glad that helped :)

Comment: @FarzadYZ Looks like the page you linked to has moved, and not sure if the document it routes you to is the right one. And I'm a bit confused because of that, and not sure if the second half of your answer directly talks about how to link to image files with Webpack with inline CSS as the primary issue, but maybe you were linking to more complete information...

Comment: @BBaysinger Thanks for the headsup. they have changed the docs quite a lot lately, specially from v1 to v2. I just modified the answer with updated links.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in a React 16.11.0 project created with create-react-app:

```
import emailIcon from '../../assets/images/footer/icons/email.png';

<div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(" + emailIcon + ")" }}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the style you try to apply is correct. In my case, `width` and `height` styles weren't applied as it was: `140px !important`, instead of just `140px`. As soon as I removed `!important`, inline style has been applied.

Answer (score -1):

Inspect image in chrome console. Open image url from rendered element in new tab. It may be wrong relative path or something wrong with server public folder setup. Try to fix image url in separate tab. Once you get the image, fix path in the component accordingly